# add css class to mysql result based on criterias

Tags: php, css

I populate a list of dates from a `MySQL`database like this:

```
<?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($list_customers)) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
            echo "<td>".$row['customer_date']."</td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
?>
```

Now I would like to add the result inside a `<span>` that changes `class=''` based on some criteria:

- If date result is within a 30 days reach from todays date, add
  `class='yellow'`
- If date result is over 30 days from today, add `class='green'`
- If date result has passed, based on todays date, add `class='red'`

Would this be possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the type of the `customer_date` field?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @David: I know you've already accepted an answer, but please read my one too; I've made a few points you probably need to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. Just compare your date with current time using a series of `if` statements and assign a variable to the class name, like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_query($list_customers)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    $class = "class='green'";
    if (strtotime($row['customer_date']) < time()) {
        $class = "class='red'";
    }elseif (strtotime($row['customer_date']) < time() + 30*24*3600) {
        $class = "class='yellow'";
    }
    echo "<td><span $class>" . $row['customer_date'] . "</span></td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's really just a simple case of writing the `if()` conditions you specified. There's no magic to it.

Firstly, we need to know what format your `customer_date` field is in. Since you're printing it directly into the HTML code I guess it's in a text format, so the first thing we need to do is convert it to a date object.

```
$custDate = new DateTime($row['customer_date']);
```

This will only work if the date is in a suitable format, but to be honest if it isn't in standard MySQL date format then you should stop now and fix that before we go any further.

You'll also need the current date as a date object:

```
$currDate = new DateTime();
```

Now you can compare them easily enough using the methods on the DateTime class:

```
$dateDiff = $currDate->diff($custDate)->days;
```

Now you've got that, you can just do your `if()` conditions.

However, I would note a few things:

1. You're using `mysql_fetch_array()`. Please note that the `mysql_` functions are considered obsolete; you should replace with `mysqli_xxx` or the PDO library wherever possible.
2. You suggest putting the class into a `<span>` inside the `<td>` -- it is possible to put the class directly into the `<td>`. This would be a cleaner option, so I'll use that in the answer, though it is up to you.
3. You suggest using class names `red`, `green`, `yellow`. Please note that this is not a particularly good use of class names. Class names should reflect what the element is actually for, rather than how it looks. This is because the whole point of using classes and separating the styles away from the HTML is so that the styles can be changed without needing to alter the HTML. But if the class names are just colour names, it ties it logically to that colour; you may just as well put the colours directly into the HTML. Better choices of class name would perhaps be something like `custExpired`, `custNearlyExpired`, etc. That would give you more flexibility later, and make the code easier to understand for anyone reading it (eg the google bot!).

So with all that in mind, here's some code for you:

```
$currDate = new DateTime();
while ($row = $mysqli->fetch_array($list_customers)) {
    $custDate = new DateTime($row['customer_date']);
    $dateDiff = $currDate->diff($custDate)->days;

    $class = '';
    if($dateDiff < 30) { $class = 'custNearlyExpired'; }
    if($dateDiff < 0) { $class = 'custExpired'; }

    echo "<td class='custDate {$class}>{$row['customer_date']}</td>\n";
}
```

and CSS:

```
td.custDate {
    background: green;
}
td.custDate.custNearlyExpired {
    background: yellow;
}

td.custDate.custExpired {
    background: red;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That was an awesome comment. Thank you so much for taking your time to do that! I learned a lot.

Comment: No worries. It's worthwhile sometime taking the time. (while StackOverflow is a great sites, one of the problems with it is that the turnaround of question -> answer is so quick that one often feels pressure to write a short answer just to be first. But in a lot of cases the short answer may work, but may not necessarily the best answer. There's always a lot to learn, and there's even things in this answer that could be improved, but I hope it's been helpful for you, and maybe even for others too.